# Amazon AWS EC2 - Elastic IP - can i mirror my site closing certain ports?

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

THE MISSION:
I have a development environment running on an Amazon AWS EC2 virtual server which i want to have tested by third parties.

THE PROBLEM:
I do NOT trust the companies who will test it not to sabotage environment and / or steal code.  Therefore, i don't want them to know URL's, permanent IP's or even to access the web pages, which they could eventually use a crawler to find.

My environment includes web applications and socket servers.  I do NOT want to expose the web applications, while giving access only to socket servers.

THE CONCEPT:
I have opted to use a secondary, impermanent Elastic IP pointing to the environment.  this IP will be destroyed after 1 or 2 days, after basic tests have run.  Subject to change (depending on suggestions from this thread).

THE QUESTION:
Can i create a secondary Elastic IP instance that allows access only to ports 5000-5100?  If so, how?

THE ALTERNATIVE: In case this is not the most efficient procedure, what alternative would you propose?

Answer (score 0):

MY SOLUTIONS: followed [FAQ Launching Instance From Backup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html)

1. create snapshot
2. create image from snapshot (snapshot menu - create image tag)
3. instances - launch instance
4. choose image created from snapshot as your root volume
5. edit security groups (opened port range for sockets only, no web)
6. deleted all web code from this instance
7. after 2 days, will delete instance

followed [Create Image From, Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html)

1. select (exclusively) running instance you wish to mirror
2. right click on selected instance
3. choose create image from dropdown
4. to 7. same as above

this second solution seems to be more stable (especially re: status check and connectivity issues).

any better solutions?  thanx!